# Html template for prototype

Tags: html

Anybody knows where to find some simple html templates for when creating a new website prototype?

With basic css, page structure and etc...

It's boring not to have anything when you are creating a new website.

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are good resources for CSS templates or templated layout sites?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/522856/what-are-good-resources-for-css-templates-or-templated-layout-sites)

Answer (score 0):

Try http://www.templatemonster.com/ just have a look at their templates an save them to desktop mark this as answered if this is has answered your question